# Context-Free grammar - Normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, conjunctive-normal-form

Termials = a,b,c.
non-Termials = A,S.
Production Rules:
(1) S → aS
(2) S → bA
(3) A → bA
(4) A → cA
(5) A → c
(6) S → a
  How do you write the following in normal form, I understand that it is currently not a context free grammar language of normal form , so I want to modify to be.

Comment: How do you convert different values for one non - terminal of production rules to CNF?

Comment: By CNF in your comment you mean Chomsky Normal Form? In the question you do not specifiy. There are also Greibach Normal Form and other normal forms for CFG. For CNF you can easily find conversion algorithms.

Comment: @Sue A good start is to actually understand the grammar you're given.  Can you describe what the words it creates are?